# What would be the best practice when it comes to using multiple injected DAOs

Tags: java, spring, gwt, jpa, guice

Off the top of my head i am thinking of writing my server-side tasks as one big service and injecting all dao objects within that service- something like this:

```
public class MyServiceImpl extends RemoteServiceServlet implements MyService {
@Inject 
MyDAO1 myDAO1;
@Inject 
MyDAO2 myDAO2;
@Inject 
MyDAO3 myDAO3;

...
//20  methods
//
}
```

Is one big service the way to go or is  there some other, better pattern for this ?

Comment: I think this covers it: http://stackoverflow.com/a/16234079/210445

Comment: @osh, no, one large service is not good since it violates [single responsibility principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_responsibility_principle). You are essentially creating god object which would be very hard to support. You should think about which responsibilities your server-side layer has and then you should carefully divide these responsibilities among several services.

Answer (score 0):

You should buid a service for each "domain" of tasks. For example, a service for User Management, with methods that allows registering new users, send recovering password e-mails, disable temporarily a user, get a list of currently enabled users, etc.

I suggest you take a look at the ServiceLayer pattern described on Martin Fowler's `Patterns of Enterprise Application Architecture` (http://martinfowler.com/books/eaa.html).

> A Service Layer defines an application's boundary [Cockburn PloP] and
>   its set of available operations from the perspective of interfacing
>   client layers. It encapsulates the application's business logic,
>   controlling transactions and coor-dinating responses in the
>   implementation of its operations (http://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/serviceLayer.html)